# php itertation loop in hidden input not iterating

Tags: php, iteration, hidden-field

I've got one nagging little bug in this script. I'm going through my cart items and passing them into hidden inputs. The cart_id ($obj->id) is working fine into the value="" but my iteration loop that gives each value a unique name="" (cart_id_1, cart_id_2 etc) is NOT iterating.

```
<?php         

           $pass_cart_q = "SELECT c.id FROM carts AS c WHERE c.user_session_id='$sid'";
           $result = $mysqli->query($pass_cart_q);

                    $i = 1; 
                while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {

                    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"cart_id_".$i."\" value=\"  .$obj->id.  \"><br>";  
                    $i = $i++;
                }
                mysqli_close();?>
```

Each name field is coming through as cart_id_1

Comment: I've just found the thread that states you can cast a hidden field into an array using square brackets - name="name[]" ... I was operating on the assumption that I would be overwriting the values, but I will see if this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$i=$i++;
```

That's the problem just do:

```
 $i++
```

Answer (score 2):

Please replace `$i = $i++;` with just `$i++`.

```
$i = 1;
$i = $i++;

echo $i, "\n"; // 1

$i = 1;
$i = ++$i;

echo $i, "\n"; // 2

$i = 1;
$i++;

echo $i, "\n"; // 2

$i = 1;
++$i;

echo $i, "\n"; // 2
```

Comment: The increment operator VAR++ returns the value of VAR and afterwards increasing the value of VAR by one. You may simply use VAR++ as suggested or VAR = ++VAR, to get the already increased value.

Comment: Yes! The interesting thing is with `$i = $i++` that after assigning the value of the right `$i` to the left `$i` the incrementor does not operate on our left `$i`. There are at that time apparently two different references for the same variable name.

Answer (score 0):

What `$i = $i++` will cause it literally this: "make `$i` equal to `$i` and then increase it by one", but the `$i` will still remain the same. To solve this, simply replace `$i = $i++;` with `$i++`.

## [Manual Entry](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)

Comment: Why the `$i` will still remain the same?

Answer (score 0):

you are assigning the incremented value to `$i` variable. and hence it is not able to iterate. instead you should remove that assignment variable `$i` and it should only be `$i++`